# Documentation on \ref and \label behaviour with regard to newline, tab, etc

Tags: cross-referencing

It seems that `\ref` and `\label` matches newline with whitespaces: i.e. the following pair works

```
\label{foo
bar}
\ref{foo bar}
```

And tabs works similarly.

Is there any documentation on this behaviour and what characters are treated as such?

Comment: this is unrelated to `\label` you would see same just in normal text `hello<newline>world` will parse as `hello world`

Comment: that is: the argument passed to `label` is `foo bar`  so it can not distinguish the newline (with normal catcode settings)

Comment: I see! Is there a place I can find documentation on what other characters are indistinguishable from whitespace?

Comment: any character of catcode 10, try using `fooXbar` in the scope of `\catcode\`X=10 `

Comment: But even if spaces work, I would avoid them in labels.